# Is TCP more secure than UDP?

Tags: confidentiality, tcp, udp

I am referring to confidentiality not integrity. are there any security features that UDP lack compared to TCP?

According to this paragraph

> While TACACS uses UDP port 49, TACACS+ uses TCP port 49 for increased reliability

I am not sure if reliability means integrity here or a mixture of confidentiality and integrity